# Перехват YUV

Tags: web-camera, hex, usb

Перехватчиком хватаю данные из USB камеры. Данные в 16 виде. Поток идет в формате YUV 4:2:2 (YUY2).  
Не могу в этих данных понять, где сама картинка, откуда резать и до куда чтоб из YUV перевести в JPG ?

Comment: не помню, есть ли там заголовок, но можно посмотреть. Собственно сама картинка будет занимать ширина*высота*2 байт, пиксели будут расположены [так](http://www.videohelp.com/forum/images/guides/p1363566/yuy2.jpg). Но я бы взял ffmpeg - он умеет все сделать сам.

Comment: ffmpeg понимаю что умеет сам. Но нужно делать самому потому что все это будет крутится в прошивке модуля. НУ я понимаю что пиксели будут расположены таким образом, но откуда их начинать искать эти пиксели, в том вся и суть откуда начинать искать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Легкий гуглинг сразу дает пример - [статья](http://www.twam.info/linux/v4l2grab-grabbing-jpegs-from-v4l2-devices). Там же есть ссылка на сорцы на сях.

Comment: дам там есть исходники. но они работают через дрова причем Линуховские. А мне нужно разбирать именно HEX "0C 8D CC AD 4D 0D E8 CA 50 0D 75 07 86 91 86 73" именно во всем потоке выдрать начало картинки в YUV и конец. чтоб потом уже ее привести в jpg

Comment: По такому куску вряд ли кто то сможет помочь. Эти данные могут быть с середины потока - тут только медитация. Так как картинка как минимум 320 на 240 (да, может и меньше, но я сомневаюсь), то нужно как минимум 150к данных (это будет один кадр).
я бы показал камере красный/зеленый фон и смотрел на последовательности.

Comment: картинка 640 х 480. Ну это кусок HEX просто для наглядности.  А вот с зеленым Кадром или красным кадром. замечательная подсказка. щас буду пробывать

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста я вот нашел самый большой объем в данных. но суть в том что и IN  и OUT совершенно одинаковые. Это так и должно быть?  по идеии именно там и должна быть картинка

Comment: А что такое IN и OUT?

Comment: IN это прочитанная информация. OUT это отправленная информация.   IN то нам прислала камера, OUT что ты отправили камере

Comment: Видимо я не владею контекстом. Так как для меня это ничего не уточняет:)